# How to change UICollectionView Scroll Direction?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have successfully implemented a `UICollectionView`. Is it possible to change the `scrollDirection`?

Can you please show how to implement it programmatically?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I change the scroll direction in UICollectionView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464153/how-can-i-change-the-scroll-direction-in-uicollectionview)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

This is how you create it in code with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

or if you are working with an existent collection view

```
if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
}
```

Comment: When I tried to handle it in "viewWillTransition" method, its crashing: "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value". What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout**

[UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayoutconfiguration) has a [scrollDirection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayoutconfiguration/3199222-scrolldirection) property. Changing it will affect the whole collection view. You can also set separate scroll direction for each section if needed.

```
let configuration = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
configuration.scrollDirection = .vertical

collectionView.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(
    sectionProvider: { section, environment in
        // Return section
    },
    configuration: configuration
)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you did not use storyboard and all is done with programmatically.
so when we do that like this:

```
  lazy var snapCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, 
        collectionViewLayout: layout)
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "background")
        return collectionView
    }()
```