# How can I set custom horizontal scroll for Collection View in Swift, XCode?

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, collectionview

I want to set custom horizontal scroll for my CollectionView, that it will be scrolling by 1 cell (not by the whole width of my screen).

I could set HORIZONTAL scroll, but not custom. (See screens). 
1 screen: my extension of my collectionView for UIScrollViewDelegate. 
*I saw, that in console (see too) "x" - my offset = 290 - it's true! But on fact it is not 290. Paging was marked in "true" 2 screen: delegate and dataSource.

[image]

Help, please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the scroll direction in UICollectionView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464153/how-can-i-change-the-scroll-direction-in-uicollectionview)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could create a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout that will center the cells in the screen and then page one at a time. Karmadust have written a good blog post that I have successfully used in the past to do the same thing

http://blog.karmadust.com/centered-paging-with-preview-cells-on-uicollectionview/

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set your collectionView scroll direction horizontal (`UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal`)  and set `pagingEnabled` to **YES**

It means your collection view will be scroll horizontally with one by one cell.

Set horizontal direction *(Select collection view from XIB or Storyboard)*

[image]

And for set pagination enable

```
myCollectionView.pagingEnabled = true
```

**Updated :**

You should use of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` delegate

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        var height = 101.7 // set height as you want
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
```

Comment: pagingEnabled to YES - it is was in my project
But I don't understand about UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal. Could you explain, please?

Comment: It was in my project. The problem is that I have horizontal scroll, but my scroll is not by one cell (I have not standart width of cell)

Comment: can't get you! do you want to display only one cell on screen? when user scroll further then display second one ?

Comment: After several swipes I have: [link](http://pixs.ru/showimage/BCdXOhWfu1_3765837_28256317.jpg) (my picture does not fit on the screen completely)
But I want after N swipes: [link](http://pixs.ru/showimage/cN8n7CYT09_4565560_28256310.jpg)

Comment: Check updated answer you may be get by UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Answer (score 0):

If using storyBoard the go to collection view and select the right handed tab "show the size inspector" and change

```
minimum spacing for cells = 0
minimum spacing for lines = 0
```

if you want to change directly from code then implement these UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout methods

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout 
       collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
   minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

must be remember scrolling direction set horizontal 
and pagination enabled

and implement this delegate methods into code

```
  extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout 
 collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: 
 IndexPath) -> CGSize {
      return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 
collectionView.frame.size.height)
     }
 }
```